# In ionic app i want show data into modal and show selected data in registration form

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, ionic-view

### Here is my code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uEoPfsuvO4MzB1VW9pV0xNcVk

Here is my registration form in which I want to show state data in modal when I click on input or list item. After select state from modal have to show data in input or list-item and after that show all city related to state I selected and show it in modal and after select show it in input or list-item on my registration page.

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: please show us the code you already have :)

Comment: Ok.I ll upload it.

Comment: I uploaded code on google drive you could check it.